# How To Make Connection To WordPress Data Base In A Plugin?

Tags: php, database, mysql, wp-config, table

I am learning Plugins and I am trying to connect WordPress database `wp-config.php` in my Plugin PHP code. Currently for checking my code, I used the below connection and it is working fine. Now I converted it into a WordPress plugin so anyone can use this but now its time to make WordPress database connection.

```
//Connection To DataBase
$host = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
$username = "XXXXXXXXXX";
$password = "XXXXXXXXXX";
$dbname = "XXXXXXXXXXXX";
$connection = mysql_connect($host, $username, $password);
mysql_select_db($dbname);
```

So How to insert `wp-config.php` like something `require_once(wp-config.php');` in plugin instead of above code to make WordPress SQL database connection in my plugin file?

Comment: If you want to make plugin in **wordpress** then you dont need to connect with database like we do in **PHP**. For example, you can check out default plugin of wordpress **Hello World** 's code.

Comment: You don't want any connection while doing wordpress plugin. just use " global $wpdb;" and then use that $wpdb to create table,insert,update and all..

Comment: @Rohil_PHPBeginner Can you mention here what I ask...???

Comment: @Ammu Nice tip but I am new so can you share the basic queries of `$wpdb;` to `INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE,WHERE` like `$sql= "SELECT ID FROM wp_posts WHERE post_name = 'hello-world'";` in the answer...

Comment: [Read whole page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) to get idea about `$wpdb` .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the answer my self. First open your `wp-config.php` and check the bottom of file that Is that contain the below code?...

```
if ( !defined('ABSPATH') )
    define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');
```

If yes then add the below code to make the connection in your plugin PHP files to connect with `wp-config.php` file that contain Database Name, Database UserName, Database Password, Database Host... ...

```
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-config.php');
$connection = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
mysqli_select_db($connection, DB_NAME);
```

And you will get connection to WordPress database...